# Can I Use Google OAuth 2.0 account with 1.0 hybrid protocol

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

For working with Google using 1.0 protocol, applications were required to be registered using https://accounts.google.com/ManageDomains which provided a ConsumerKey and a ConsumerSecret to access feeds.

Newer application registrations are instead done using https://code.google.com/apis/ which provides ClientID, RedirectURL etc. (but not consumer key) as it is based on OAuth 2.0

Question: Is it possible to run an application created with Google APIs (OAuth 2.0) to work with an 1.0a OAuth flow? If yes, what field should be considered as a ConsumerKey?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended that you use OAuth2 Registration for OAuth1 flows. The OAuth1 approval page will not look very nice to your users. Google's consumer_key and client_id are roughly equivalent, However, Google's OAuth1 approval page shows the raw value of consumer_key (client_id). The Application brand info will not be shown and instead you'll see the client_id value. 12345.apps.googleusercontent.com.

If you want to do the OAuth1 hybrid protocol, OAuth2 is a naturally 'hybrid' protocol and can do identity as well as data access control.

Comment: OAuth 2.0 doesn't return email ID but Oauth1.0 Hybrid does. Anyways, this issue is resolved. User needs to register application in "Manage Your Domains" section of Google to obtain ConsumerKey (Which is different from ClientId)

Comment: The statement about email id is not correct. You can get all the info you get via OAuth1 with OAuth2. use the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email scope. If you are just designing you application now, you really should switch to OAuth2. OAuth1 is deprecated.